# Pass data from a service to current activity

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm building a chat application that uses GCM to push the messages and the notifications.

In the app, I have an activity which lists the conversation threads (`ConversationListActivity`) and an activity which shows the conversation inside the thread (`ConversationActivity`).

I capture new messages in GCMIntentService's onMessage method. The notification works and the message is recorded as expected.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
  @Override
  protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String sender = extras.getString("sender");
    String message = extras.getString("message");

    ConversationModel model = new ConversationModel(context);
    model.open();
    model.createMessage(sender, message.trim(), true, true, ConversationMessage.STATUS_SENT);
    model.close();

    this.createMessageNotification(context, sender, message);
  }
}
```

The problem is, if GCM pushes a new message while `ConversationActivity` is active, I don't want it to generate a notification. Instead, I want the conversation to refresh directly.

How can I tell the active `ConversationActivity` to refresh the message list every time there is a new message from GCM?

Comment: Are you saving the message conversation in DB?

Comment: Yes, `ConversationModel` is a model class that manages the sqlite DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I'm sure that this is not the best way to do it, but at least it works for me.

Create a singleton class that derives `Handler` to store the active `ConversationActivity`.
In the `handleMessage` method, handle message that will be dispatched from the service that tells the handler to tell the activity to refresh the conversation.

```
public class ActiveMessageHandler extends Handler {

  private static ActiveMessageHandler _instance = new ActiveMessageHandler();
  private Activity _activity = null;

  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message message) {
    if(message.obj.toString().equals("gcmNewMessage") && _activity != null)
        ((ConversationActivity)_activity).repopulateList();

    super.handleMessage(message);
  }

  public static ActiveMessageHandler instance() {
    return _instance;
  }

  public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
    _activity = activity;
  }

  public Activity getActivity() {
    return _activity;
  }

}
```

Then, in `ConversationActivity`, set the activity attribute in the handler.

```
public class ConversationActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ActiveMessageHandler.instance().setActivity(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ActiveMessageHandler.instance().setActivity(null);
  }
}
```

Finally, in the service, check if the activity in the handler is not null and send a message to the handler to refresh the conversation.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String sender = extras.getString("sender");
        String message = extras.getString("message");

        ConversationModel model = new ConversationModel(context);
        model.open();
        model.createMessage(sender, message.trim(), true, true, ConversationMessage.STATUS_SENT);
        model.close();

        // if ConversationActivity is active, send a message to handler to refresh the conversation
        if(ActiveMessageHandler.instance().getActivity() != null)
        {
            Message msg = Message.obtain(ActiveMessageHandler.instance());
            msg.obj = "gcmNewMessage";
            ActiveMessageHandler.instance().sendMessage(msg);

            // Optionally, play a notification sound
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
            r.play();
        }
        else
            createMessageNotification(context, sender, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @drowneath.I dont know how efficient this is but definately it has helped me.As you said "I'm sure that this is not the best way to do it" If you find something better than this please update your answer.

Comment: You store a reference to the Activity in a static field this way. This produces a memory leak in the long run